# App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it - App downloaded from Itunes Store

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, development, facebook, setup

NOTE: I did NOT create an app, I downloaded one from the Itunes store (Likie App) and trying to synch it to my FB. I received this error message instead...please help!

Comment: Which app did you download?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your purchase history for the app and:

1. Contact the developer from the support link for that app.
2. If that fails after a reasonable amount of time (2 business days for paid apps, a week for free apps perhaps) - then use the report a problem link to report that app to Apple.